# Index data on array property

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing, data-structures, frontend

I have a collection of data, like this:

```js
const data = {
  suze: ['apples'],
  pete: ['apples', 'oranges'],
  mary: ['oranges', 'apples'],
  james: ['pears'],
  ruth: ['pears']
}
```

And I need to group them according to which fruits they sell. The order in the fruits array shouldn't matter. I would go about this like:

```js
const indexedData = {}
Object.entries(data).forEach(([name, fruits]) => {
  const id = fruits.sort().join('_')
  if (!indexedData[id]) {
    indexedData[id] = {
      fruits,
      persons: []
    }
  }
  indexedData[id].persons.push(name)
})
```

And I would get this:

```js
console.log(indexedData)
// {
//   apples: {
//     fruits: ["apples"],
//     persons: ["suze"]
//   },
//   apples_oranges: {
//     fruits: ["apples", "oranges"],
//     persons: ["pete", "mary"]
//   },
//   pears: {
//     fruits: ["pears"],
//     persons: ["james", "ruth"]
//   }
// }
```

This works fine, but I am wondering if there is a better way to create the index (`const id = fruits.sort().join('_')`).

Theoretically, someone could sell a new fruit called 'apples_oranges', and we would have a problem. I could think of ways to prevent this, like keeping track of the array length, or replacing the `_` separator with some string that would 'never' occur in a fruit name, but maybe there is a better way to go about this?

Or maybe I should handle this problem in a different way entirely?

Comment: I don't understand why you're creating that `"apples_oranges"` at all. Don't do it. Use simply `"apples"`, `"oranges"`. Say you have checkboxes with each fruit type, if one checks both "Apples" and "Oranges" that's the proper way to go query all the persons who sell both, or depending on your business logic - either one of the two.

Comment: We had a problem alike - not the same - in current project, but basically we have just chosen a character that most like won't never appear in incoming string. If that's not enough, you can go a bit deeper and try to use not one character, but few as a separator, which will have even lesser probability of appearing.
Also, as it seems a bit odd for me - have you considered not creating those joins, but instead adding pete and mary both to just apples and oranges? That would seem more natural

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `.join()` which could mess up things creating possible false-positives (as you explained),

**store the entire stringified Array** as your "ID" property using [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify):

```js
const data = {
  suze: ['apples'],
  pete: ['apples', 'oranges'],
  mary: ['oranges', 'apples'],
  james: ['pears'],
  ruth: ['pears']
};

const indexedData = Object.entries(data).reduce((ob, [name, fruits]) => {
  const id = JSON.stringify(fruits.sort());
  if (!ob[id]) ob[id] = { fruits, persons: [] };
  ob[id].persons.push(name);
  return ob;
}, {});

console.log(indexedData);
```

If needed you can even get back the array by using `JSON.parse( objKey )`

Comment: Thanks! The way you describe is the proper solution if a user would select some sellers, however this is not about UI, I need the grouping all upfront. And every seller will only belong to one group. In my case there will be hundreds of fruits, and hundreds of sellers. I can’t go over all different permutations of fruits in one go. Moreover, the fact that mary sells oranges isn’t relevant in and of itself. In my case, the only relevant question is - can you give me the group of all sellers that sell exactly the same fruits as mary.

Comment: That means that the key 'apples_oranges', in and of itself, is not relevant for me, it could be a hash derived from the array, for example. But it is essential to group only the persons that sell exactly those fruits in one bucket.

Comment: You mean as an output? That would be perfectly fine, too. For me it's about how to distinguish between ['apples', 'oranges'] and ['apples_oranges'] during the creation of this Array / Object

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217304/discussion-between-sventies-and-roko-c-buljan).

Comment: Thanks @Roko. I think that could work as well. I'm gonna try some different things as well, so not marking your answer as solved yet, but may do in the future and thanks a lot for thinking along!

Comment: @Sventies you're welcome. BTW, if you're trying to (I tried already) use `new Map` (since the property can story any primitive value (like an Array)) it will not work - therefore the solution to stringify the Array making it actually a unique identifier.